# How to make the recorded script for my .NET program work? (Problem with readers)

Tags: .net, loadrunner

I'm using HP-LoadRunner to test my .NET Windows application with load tests, I'm setting up a new load test with Virtual User Generator, I'm starting a new script with record button putting a username & password and getting into the users list in the application.

When the script is created, I opened the controller and started a new scenario with 1 user clicking at (Play) button.

An error was appearing: "Scripts you are running are invalid".

I open the errors it was written "Error: Action.cs (41,43): error CS0103: The name 'reader_1' does not exist in the current context".

What is (reader_1) and why it is not exist?

(Created record script code attached).

I tried to remove the readers, is tells me that we must include it.

```
                 lr.log("Event 2: new DataSet();");
                 DataSet_1 = new DataSet();

        #warning:  Code Generation Error
        // Found an undefined object of type System.Xml.XmlTextReader. Assigning it the name reader_1.
        // Suggested solution: adding both this type, in assembly System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, to the filter 
        // and/or any other types that return instances of this one.
        // Note:  This script will not compile as is.

        
        
    lr.log("Event 3: ((IXmlSerializable) (DataSet_1)).ReadXml(reader_1);");
    ((IXmlSerializable)(DataSet_1)).ReadXml(reader_1);
```

I expect the readers to be defined, but it is not defined.

Comment: Did you follow the "suggested solution"? What happened when you did?

Comment: where should i have?

Comment: Your posted code contains a comment telling you that this error exists and giving you a "suggested solution". I suggest you try that first.

Comment: i tried and there is no solution helping me.

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried? What error did you get, how did your code look then?

Comment: i got this error:

"Error: Action.cs (41,43): error CS0103: The name 'reader_1' does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a process issue here. You are assuming that you can go directly from recording to playback with zero modification of your test code, or even validation that it worked for a single user. You also did not take the time to view the generated test code for items that required addressing.

I think it would help to understand a few items before continuing on the answer

- What is your level of training and experience with LoadRunner?
- What is your level of experience with .Net?
- What is your level of experience with C# as a language?

Comment: i'm begginer with LoadRunner, i have 2 .net C# experts with me, i have also normal experience with .net.

Comment: training?  mentor in loadrunner?   Can you find performance issues without LoadRunner?